# android button widget with a dropdown list, what is the name of this particular widget?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-xml

Im learning android layouts and Ive noticed a particular button widget in some android apps that I would like to add to my own apps, Im just not entirely sure what its called, In some cases this button widget even will include a dropdown list here are a few examples of what Im talking about.

in the first image you will notice that the checkmark, the camera and the pencil are all sitting inside of the button widget i'm after, and in the youtube app you will notice the thumbs up, thumbs down and more buttons

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7861548/downloadable-smarter-gui-views-widgets-for-android-gui-development/7862055#7862055) which gives some good links on how to implement the "dashboard" pattern, and use the "quickaction" bar. I think this should put you on the right path. Also there is a link on how to implement the "action bar."

EDIT: According to Mighter, if you use API 1.6 - 2.3 there should be official Google samples for this now. Please see [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html).

Comment: Reason for the downvote? Was this just a drive by downvoting?

Comment: I think that it's better to use official source code in your app rather then pull bugs with third-party library.

Comment: I agree completely, and the reason I linked that answer is because it applies to APIs prior to the ones that offered this built in. So to the OP: if your API is 3.0+, then you should use the built in methods for this.

Comment: There are official samples. So to the OP, if you use API 1.6-2.3 look into new google samples.

Answer (score 1):

That's ActionBar. Native support for 3.0+ devices, and some work to do in pre 3.0-devices. You can find example in new api  14 samples(called "ActionBarCompat").